# Why does \noindent with CJK text prevent document from compiling?

Tags: cjk, xecjk

I had a large linguistics example document with example text from many different languages, which stopped compiling when I transferred it to a new Mac (with all the same software and TeX distribution). The Chinese and Japanese sections were the culprits, yet Korean displayed fine (all using xeCJK). I finally tried removing \noindent (as well as the code indentation) from the beginning of the Chinese and Japanese sections and it suddenly worked fine. But why?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[fallback]{xeCJK}

\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}

\setCJKfallbackfamilyfont{\CJKrmdefault}{AppleMyungjo}

\begin{document}

\section{Chinese (Traditional)}

構詞學

\section{Japanese}

語（ご）とは

\section{Korean} 

    \noindent 단어(單語)

\end{document}
```

This version works. With the \noindent before the Japanese and Chinese sections, it does not work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I get the same output with or without `\noindent` in all three sections. What do you mean by “it does not work”?

Comment: The code works for me (with or without `\noindent` added). And the `\noindent` is redundant since v3.2.11 (r472). You are probably using an old version of `xeCJK`. Please update your TeX system (update all packages) and try again.